# Loop over an indexed array

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [12] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 24339
                            [active] => 1
                            [lang] => en
                            [link] => http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=203859683&id=165118953&hash=545584bd3253fab9&hd=1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 24483
                            [active] => 1
                            [lang] => ru
                            [link] => http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=203859108&id=164809310&hash=5544f9e52b6ebc10&hd=1
                        )

                )

            [11] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 24016
                            [active] => 1
                            [lang] => en
                            [link] => http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=203859683&id=165118860&hash=088323c81fb1f360&hd=1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 24115
                            [active] => 1
                            [lang] => ru
                            [link] => http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=203859108&id=164809379&hash=dd49270049f5a632&hd=1
                        )

                )

            [10] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 23463
                            [active] => 1
                            [lang] => en
                            [link] => http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=203859683&id=165118763&hash=f328401f5bd7f2e4&hd=1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 23656
                            [active] => 1
                            [lang] => ru
                            [link] => http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=203859108&id=164809462&hash=7a61a9ac444e2b95&hd=1
                        )

                )

            [9] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 21815
                            [active] => 1
                            [lang] => en
                            [link] => http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=203859683&id=165118684&hash=3bbddfcc12426510&hd=1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 22406
                            [active] => 1
                            [lang] => ru
                            [link] => http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=203859108&id=164809548&hash=cd0e7f43171569a6&hd=1
                        )

                )

            [8] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 20443
                            [active] => 1
                            [lang] => en
                            [link] => http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=203859683&id=165118608&hash=26c0f730bc1dd6c3&hd=1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 20921
                            [active] => 1
                            [lang] => ru
                            [link] => http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=203859108&id=164809649&hash=47c524f47946fb96&hd=1
                        )

                )

            [7] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 19812
                            [active] => 1
                            [lang] => en
                            [link] => http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=203859683&id=165118510&hash=1243ca95114cbdf2&hd=1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 20057
                            [active] => 1
                            [lang] => ru
                            [link] => http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=203859108&id=164809741&hash=266c635751d2f9d5&hd=1
                        )

                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 19262
                            [active] => 1
                            [lang] => en
                            [link] => http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=203859683&id=165118374&hash=e947746533f9d895&hd=1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 19392
                            [active] => 1
                            [lang] => ru
                            [link] => http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=203859108&id=164809836&hash=e58901e3e2f32993&hd=1
                        )

                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 18217
                            [active] => 1
                            [lang] => en
                            [link] => http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=203859683&id=165118222&hash=3a236df89bcfaac5&hd=1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 18417
                            [active] => 1
                            [lang] => ru
                            [link] => http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=203859108&id=164809927&hash=d8a72be4d4eb7d86&hd=1
                        )

                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 17231
                            [active] => 1
                            [lang] => en
                            [link] => http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=203859683&id=165118092&hash=13e854824bde17ab&hd=1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 17603
                            [active] => 1
                            [lang] => ru
                            [link] => http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=203859108&id=164810038&hash=9d7b6a4336dd2b98&hd=1
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 15838
                            [active] => 1
                            [lang] => en
                            [link] => http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=203859683&id=165117998&hash=031a9c6d70058e4f&hd=1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 16465
                            [active] => 1
                            [lang] => ru
                            [link] => http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=203859108&id=164810119&hash=06985923604c61ca&hd=1
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 15070
                            [active] => 1
                            [lang] => en
                            [link] => http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=203859683&id=165117903&hash=b1a21a9021b74aa2&hd=1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 15284
                            [active] => 1
                            [lang] => ru
                            [link] => http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=203859108&id=164810199&hash=3b818c6ef7c7488b&hd=1
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 13663
                            [active] => 1
                            [lang] => en
                            [link] => http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=203859683&id=165117810&hash=62f01fa6c53a195f&hd=1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 14000
                            [active] => 1
                            [lang] => ru
                            [link] => http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=203859108&id=164810267&hash=60074b4f93d62429&hd=1
                        )

                )1

        )

)
```

I have the following that i have sliced from a much bigger array. Now i want to loop trough this array and filter some value's. I've used the sliced_array feature with the true option to preserve the [2] array number.

Now this array has some several sub arrays and i need some value's and some filtering. In the end result I want to create a table that lists the array numbers (1 to 12) And have the link behind it. (so a 2 column table) What i don't need is the 2nd array from the episode number. this is always the [1] array from a episode. This is the "russian" part and i don't need that in my end results.

How can i loop over this and get a simple html table as output? I've been trying with the foreach() method but for now all i get back is "Array".

*edit*
the answer was indeed to do multiple foreach.

```
<?php
    $json = file_get_contents("http://trendico.ru/api/moviebox/get_tv_data?id=1&season=7");
    $array = json_decode($json, TRUE);


//Create an index array
$indexarray = (array_values($array));

//Create an array with only the episodes 
$episodes = array_slice($indexarray, 2, 1);



foreach($array as $arrayl1) {
    foreach($arrayl1 as $arrayl2) {
        foreach($arrayl2 as $arrayl3) {
            foreach($arrayl3 as $key => $val) {
                echo "$key=>$val"."<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Continue foreaching until you reach the desired value

Comment: You'll need nested `for each`

Comment: What does your code look like now? (that slices the array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use recursive function and `is_array`.

```
function doSomething(&$complex_array){
foreach ($complex_array as $n => $v)
{
    if (is_array($v))
        doSomething($v);
    else
        do whatever you want to do with a single node
}}
```

Comment: This answer should be in comment! :)

Comment: @VinothBabu that requires 50 rep, which he (yet) doesn't have.

Comment: You all helped me very much by steering me in the right direction. Now I only need to put it all together :)

Answer (score 2):

you can loop inside all your array untill you reach data you need, since data is in 4th level so let's loop 4 times

```
foreach($array as $arrayl1) {
    foreach($arrayl1 as $arrayl2) {
        foreach($arrayl2 as $arrayl3) {
            foreach($arrayl3 as $key => $val) {
                echo "$key=>$val"."<br>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this will output

```
id=>24339
active=>1
lang=>en
link=>http://vk.com/video_ext.php?oid=203859683&id=165118953&hash=545584bd3253fab9&hd=1
id=>24483
active=>1
lang=>ru // and so on
```

Comment: Thank you :) I didn't know it would be this simple... any idea how i can filter out the Array[0] from an episode with the ru language?

Comment: @Michel Beld Take a look to my answer maybe that helps a little.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably not deep enough this should work:

```
foreach($array[2] as $link){
      if($choice == 'eng'){
          // the English
          echo $link[0]['id'] . " - ". $link[0]['link'];
      }
      elseif($choice == 'ru'){
          // the Russian
          echo $link[1]['id'] . " - ". $link[1]['link'];
      }
}
```

$array is the variable you use to store your multidimensional array the first element is an array with the key 2. I don't know why!? But still loop trough the array inside the array.

Comment: It has the number two because it's an slice from an bigger array. And i've used the true option from the slice_array function to preserve that array number. But without the true option it would start @ zero.

Comment: Oke that sounds logical. But still when there is only one top array why loop over it just point to it directly.

Comment: I can just remove the true part and have the array starting at zero. With the help of Fabio I indeed received output. And i've updated the original question with the solution so far. Now i need to incorporate your suggestion for the filtering part.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
foreach($array as $smaller){
  foreach($smaller as $link){
     echo $link[0]['id'] . " > ". $link[0]['link']
  }
}
```